# How can I hedge basis risk?

Tags: derivatives, hedging

Let's say we caught arbitrage between spot and futures, we sold futures and bought spot. The risk-free rate is 5%, and our arbitrage position profit is 5.5%. When the interest rates increase to 6% before maturity, I will lose money.(This is called basis risk, I think)
How can I hedge this risk? Which derivatives instrument is appropriate?

Thanks

Comment: What futures are you referring?  Treasury futures, Equity futures...?

Comment: @AlRacoon equity futures and fx futures